# PostgreSQL efficient query with filter over boolean

Tags: postgresql

There's table with 15M rows holding user's inbox data

```
 user_id         | integer                  | not null
 subject         | character varying(255)   | not null 
...
 last_message_id | integer                  | 
 last_message_at | timestamp with time zone |
 deleted_at      | timestamp with time zone |
```

**Here's slow query in nutshell:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM dialogs 
WHERE user_id = 1234 
AND deleted_at IS NULL 
LIMIT 21
```

**Full query:**
(irrelevant fields deleted)

```
SELECT "dialogs"."id", "dialogs"."subject", "dialogs"."product_id", "dialogs"."user_id", "dialogs"."participant_id", "dialogs"."thread_id", "dialogs"."last_message_id", "dialogs"."last_message_at", "dialogs"."read_at", "dialogs"."deleted_at", "products"."id", ... , T4."id", ... , "messages"."id", ...,  
FROM "dialogs" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" ON ("dialogs"."product_id" = "products"."id") 
INNER JOIN "auth_user" T4 ON ("dialogs"."participant_id" = T4."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "messages" ON ("dialogs"."last_message_id" = "messages"."id") 
WHERE ("dialogs"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "dialogs"."user_id" = 9069) 
ORDER BY "dialogs"."last_message_id" DESC
LIMIT 21;
```

**EXPLAIN:**

```
Limit  (cost=1.85..28061.24 rows=21 width=1693) (actual time=4.700..93087.871 rows=17 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.85..9707215.30 rows=7265 width=1693) (actual time=4.699..93087.861 rows=17 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.41..9647421.07 rows=7265 width=1457) (actual time=4.689..93062.481 rows=17 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.99..9611285.66 rows=7265 width=1115) (actual time=4.676..93062.292 rows=17 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan Backward using dialogs_last_message_id on dialogs  (cost=0.56..9554417.92 rows=7265 width=102) (actual time=4.629..93062.050 rows=17 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((deleted_at IS NULL) AND (user_id = 9069))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 6852907
                    ->  Index Scan using products_pkey on products  (cost=0.43..7.82 rows=1 width=1013) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=17)
                          Index Cond: (dialogs.product_id = id)
              ->  Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user t4  (cost=0.42..4.96 rows=1 width=342) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=17)
                    Index Cond: (id = dialogs.participant_id)
        ->  Index Scan using messages_pkey on messages  (cost=0.44..8.22 rows=1 width=236) (actual time=1.491..1.492 rows=1 loops=17)
              Index Cond: (dialogs.last_message_id = id)
Total runtime: 93091.494 ms
(14 rows)
```

- `OFFSET` is not used
- There's index on `user_id` field.
- Index on `deleted_at` isn't used because of high selectivity (90% values are actually NULL). Partial index (`... WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`) won't help either.
- It gets especially slow if query hits some part of results that were created long time ago. Then query has to filter and discard millions of rows in between.

**List of indexes:**

```
Indexes:
    "dialogs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "dialogs_deleted_at_d57b320e_uniq" btree (deleted_at) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
    "dialogs_last_message_id" btree (last_message_id)
    "dialogs_participant_id" btree (participant_id)
    "dialogs_product_id" btree (product_id)
    "dialogs_thread_id" btree (thread_id)
    "dialogs_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

Currently I'm thinking about querying only recent data (i.e. `... WHERE last_message_at > <date 3-6 month ago>` with appropriate index (BRIN?).

What is best practice to speed up such queries?

Comment: If you run the explain query using only `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` do you see anticipated speeds? If so I'd suggest putting an index on both `user_id` and `deleted_at` columns in the same index. Usually this will be required because you can't merge two individual indices the way you'd imagine, but storing an index over multiple columns produces the faster query times you're expecting.

Comment: you say the index on deleted_at isn't used. But your explain shows it is, there is no seq scan. It's a backwards index scan on `dialogs_last_message_id`. What's wrong? Paste the full query plan.

Comment: Please post your index definitions too. What do you mean by *Partial index won't help either*? An index on `user_id` where `deleted_at IS NULL` should help.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - I guess it's `user_id` index being used. Filter on deleted_at just loop over result set and dumb-compare deleted_at with NULL until there's 11 items in result.

Comment: @pozs - I meant conditional index. I already have it - `"dialogs_deleted_at_d57b320e_uniq" btree (deleted_at) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`. Thanks I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - actually second time when I captured explain output, that particular user had 11 recent items, so yeah, query time was ok. But first time it was pretty bad because some items in result where created few years ago, so it had to filter/discard millions of rows. The explain output was exactly the same (except timing) - total running time was around 14 sec (!). But thanks for suggestion, I increased `LIMIT` to 21 to capture some  of old results.

Comment: I would try an index on "btree (user_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL"

Comment: Is it just me, or your `EXPLAIN` output does not match your query at all? It involves several other tables (messages, auth_user, products) that are not in your query.

Comment: Also note that a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` does not make any sense.

Comment: @jcaron - There are few joins - but they are pretty fast. `ORDER BY` also present. Added actual query

Comment: Start by creating a partial index on (user_id, last_message_id) with a condition `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`.

Comment: @exslim what's your value of `work_mem` and `shared_buffers`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll 20Mb, 4GB corresponding

Comment: @exslim we know from your query plan that `dialogs_deleted_at_d57b320e_uniq` isn't be used at all. So nuke it. And instead create an index on `(user_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` That should have far more selectivity and be used by the query planner. That *should* speed it. Alternatively, I think dropping the index on USER_ID, and recreating another unique one on (USER_ID, DELETED_AT) will also clear it up. Be sure to `vacuum analyze` after you create these indexes.

Comment: @jcaron - your index suggestion is superb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in comments:

Start by creating a partial index on `(user_id, last_message_id)` with a condition `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`

Per your answer, this seems to be quite effective :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the results of solutions I tried

1) Index `(user_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` is used in rare cases, depending on certain values `user_id` in `WHERE user_id = ?` condition. Most of the time query has to filter out rows as previously.

2) The greatest speedup was achieved using 
`(user_id, last_message_id) WHERE deleted_at IS NULL` index. While it's 2.5x bigger than other tested indexes, it's used all the time and is very fast. Here's resulting query plan

```
Limit  (cost=1.72..270.45 rows=11 width=1308) (actual time=0.105..0.468 rows=8 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.72..247038.21 rows=10112 width=1308) (actual time=0.104..0.465 rows=8 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..164532.13 rows=10112 width=1072) (actual time=0.071..0.293 rows=8 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.86..116292.45 rows=10112 width=736) (actual time=0.057..0.198 rows=8 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan Backward using dialogs_user_id_last_message_id_d57b320e on dialogs  (cost=0.43..38842.21 rows=10112 width=102) (actual time=0.038..0.084 rows=8 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (user_id = 9069)
                     ->  Index Scan using products_pkey on products  (cost=0.43..7.65 rows=1 width=634) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=8)
                           Index Cond: (dialogs.product_id = id)
               ->  Index Scan using auth_user_pkey on auth_user t4  (cost=0.42..4.76 rows=1 width=336) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=8)
                     Index Cond: (id = dialogs.participant_id)
         ->  Index Scan using messages_pkey on messages  (cost=0.44..8.15 rows=1 width=236) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=8)
               Index Cond: (dialogs.last_message_id = id)
 Total runtime: 0.678 ms
```

Thanks @jcaron. Your suggestion should be an accepted answer.